# Why is a deluge startup script necessary?

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi, init, torrent

I'm currently working on making a spare Raspberry Pi into a headless BitTorrent box, using Deluge.

Most guides on setting up Deluge on Linux include a custom startup script that will be run at boot. However, when you're SSH'd into the Pi, you can start the *deluged* daemon by simply typing in "deluged".

However, when I wrote a basic bash script which ran this command, put it in /etc/init.d/ and added it using update-rc.d, it didn't work.

```
nano /etc/init.d/startdeluged.sh
chmod 755 /etc/init.d/startdeluged.sh
update-rc.d startdeluged.sh defaults
```

The bash script contained this:

```
#!/bin/sh

deluged
exit
```

I'm new to setting up startup scripts on Linux, and I'm just wondering why a special script is necessary when simply running a command in the Terminal has the same effect. Does it have anything to do with the user who is entering the command?

Answer (score 1):

You must add the begin init infos after `#!/bin/sh`. It looks like that :

```
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          scriptname
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Start daemon at boot time
# Description:       Enable service provided by daemon.
### END INIT INFO
```

More infos there : https://wiki.debian.org/LSBInitScripts

The script at this page may interest you : http://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/UserGuide/Service/DebianUbuntuInitd